# recognize long tap without mouseup

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, mobile-safari

I try to recognize a long tap to start a shake animation but I want to start it while the button is pressed not after I get the mouseup event. Till now I have the following code which performs exactly what I don't want but it's a beginning..

```
var offset = 10;
$('body').on('mousedown','.img-select', function (e) {
    $(this).data('start', new Date().getTime());
}).on('mouseup','.img-select', function (e) {
    if (new Date().getTime() >= ($(this).data('start') + offset)) {
        this.blur(); //to avoid a selectbox from opening
        window.focus(); //to avoid a selectbox from opening
        $('.img-item').addClass('shake');
    }
}).on('mouseleave','.img-select', function (e) {
    start = 0;
});
```

From @prajmus suggested Idea:

```
$('body').on('mousedown','.img-select', function (e) {
    //$(this).data('start', new Date().getTime());
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('.img-item').addClass('shake');
    },1000);
}).on('mouseup','.img-select', function (e) {
    /*if (new Date().getTime() >= ($(this).data('start') + offset)) {
        this.blur();
        window.focus();
        $('.img-item').addClass('shake');
    }else{

    }*/
}).on('mouseleave','.img-select', function (e) {
    start = 0;
});
```

It appears that the code inside my mousedown event handler first launched when I released the button ?!

And for some reason the code inside my timeout recommended from @prajmus wasn't executed at all.

In my imagination it should like you hold an app icon in ios..

Comment: You can use `setTimeout` in mousedown, and delete this timeout in mouseup. This way if desired timeout passed the shake will happen, if not you will delete it's execution.

Comment: @prajmus tried this but it appears that the timeout first executes after I got away from the button..

Comment: Maybe the timeout value is too short ? `setTimeout` and `Date.getTime()` use msecs, so your offset of 10 is soo short

Comment: @prajmus I tried it as shown in my edit but it executes a second after I released the button again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign the timer to a variable:

```
var timeout;
$('body').on('mousedown','.img-select', function (e) {
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){
      $('.img-item').addClass('shake');
    },1000);
}).on('mouseup','.img-select', function (e) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
}).on('mouseleave','.img-select', function (e) {
    start = 0;
});
```

Check out [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a04Ltez2/)

Comment: yes it works in jsfiddle but for some reasons not for me, with your code added it doesn't work at all now. not even a second after I released it...

Comment: You have to hold it pressed for 1 second. It's hard to tell what can be wrong with just this little code. The example itself is perfectly good.

Comment: yeah i'm aware of this, I'm gonna insert some log commands to see what happens and come back with the result

Comment: The Result of my little logging fun is that the code inside the timeout wasn't even executed so I deleted the timeout to see what happens with only my addClass in it and it appears that still then the class is added not until I released the button...

Comment: Issued to the fact that I'm using this code on a ipad it doesn't work I had to use `touchstart`and `touchend`instead of `mousedown` and `mouseup`. But of course I forgot to say that i'm on a ipad..